# TRying to creat a stack class whare on class can handle diffrent data types

Tags: java

I created a class to simulate a stack.  Right now the type is fixed to float.  I'v seen in  java util class they have a stack class ware you can define the type.

I could not find anything on how to creat a class where a type for one of its verbols can be define when the object is created.  I tried googling java template totiol, I think in c they called this templates.

so I have the classpublic class cStack {

```
float data[];
int size=0;
int pes=0;

cStack(int size)
{
    data=new float[size];
    pes=0;
}
```

now data is def as a float, I would like it so when I create the class I can set the type. So it can hold floats, or integers or strings.

Comment: google "java generics". You'll also need to know about primitive wrapper classes eg. java.lang.Integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is generic LinkedStack implementation from Bruce Eckel's "[Thinking in Java](http://books.google.com.ua/books/about/Thinking_in_Java.html?id=Ql6QgWf6i7cC&redir_esc=y)":

```
    public class LinkedStack<T> {
        private static class Node<U> {
            U item;
            Node<U> next;

            Node() {
                item = null;
                next = null;
            }

            Node(U item, Node<U> next) {
                this.item = item;
                this.next = next;
            }

            boolean end() {
                return item == null && next == null;
            }
        }

        private Node<T> top = new Node<T>(); // End sentinel

        public void push(T item) {
            top = new Node<T>(item, top);
        }

        public T pop() {
            T result = top.item;
            if (!top.end())
                top = top.next;
            return result;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            LinkedStack<String> lss = new LinkedStack<String>();
            for (String s : "Phasers on stun!".split(" "))
                lss.push(s);
            String s;
            while ((s = lss.pop()) != null)
                System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
```

I'll recommend you to read the whole book and especially the "Generics" chapter.